# How to set initial active slide to different index in swiperjs ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js, react-swiper

I want to set the index of the swiper's active slide to the center position?
[As you can see in picture the active index is set to 0, I want it be number 3, i.e: middle and it should remain middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nDnN.png)

```
 <Swiper
      grabCursor={true}
      spaceBetween={10}
      modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
      slidesPerView={7}
    //  activeSlideKey={3}
      slideActiveClass={styles.activeSlider}
    >
      {options.map((option) => () => <SwiperSlide key={option}>{option}</SwiperSlide>)}
    </Swiper>
```

activeSlideKey is just for reference. It does not work.

Answer (score 8):

Very simple.

Use API Parameter `initialSlide` (0 == first slide, 1 == second slide and so on) - **Index number of initial slide**.
https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-initialSlide

```
<Swiper
  initialSlide="3"
  navigation={true}
  modules={[Navigation]}
  className="mySwiper"
>
```

Combine if you want with `centeredSlides ={true}` & `loop={true}`.

Centered demo:
https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered

Comment: i tried this, and its not working: https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-centered-react-forked-4glxt3?file=/src/App.jsx

Comment: For me it is working (Start on slide 4) on your sandbox.

Comment: you're right, now it works for me as well, i dont know what changed.

Answer (score -5):

```
<Swiper
centeredSlides ={true}
>
...
</Swiper>
```

Comment: This is *completely* irrelevant.